# Intercept media keys on ASUS laptop

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-events

I have an ASUS laptop (F50SF) and I was playing around in C++ trying to intercept the multimedia keys (next track, previous track, play/pause, etc.), but I cannot figure out exactly how to do this. I tried `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK)` but to no avail.

I know it is possible (and that the keys are working in the first place) because these keys work fine in Windows Media Player.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the ATK Media utility provided by Asus is completely locked and instead of emiting keyboard events (like normal media keys), it maps them to specific apps. The order and name of apps that it looks for change depending on version and system, but luckily there's a fix!

I just came across the solution for this after some time reading a bunch of sites.

1. Download the rar package from this blog post: http://3mptylab.blogspot.it/2012/09/how-to-make-asus-notebooks-media-keys.html
2. Stop the current DMedia.exe process.
3. Go to your ATK Media install folder (normally C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ATK Package\ATK Media) and rename DMedia.exe to DMedia.exe.old (just to be safe).
4. Put DMedia.exe you'll find in the RAR into the ATK Media dir. Double click it to run it but it gets run at boot anyway.
5. Check if the media keys work as they should. Grab a beer or watch a movie if it works!

I just tested it in my Asus U30Jc under Win8 Pro 64-bits and works great! This tool actually maps generic keyboard events to the media keys in the integrated keyboard, so they work with any app enabled for this (in some cases like Winamp you might need to enable global keys).

Comment: Cool, thanks! To be honest, I can't even remember why I asked this question now (though I am still using my Asus laptop). Hopefully somebody else will benefit!

Comment: Works to make media keys work on Asus N56JR. Thanks!

Comment: AVG tells me the file is infected: http://www.avgthreatlabs.com/virus-and-malware-information/info/crypt_c/?name=Crypt_c.AABF

Comment: @Sonny: Hmm, mixed bag of [results](http://virusscan.jotti.org/en/scanresult/d8eb4e65a94203d5b1b17665e1e528f3e3ffb57a/db6043f455f4398789e418e70afaf9cc705a6f86) over at Jotti. Might be infected, but I'm inclined to believe they're false positives (because of the nature of the application and the extremely narrow target audience of the patch). Trust your own judgement, of course :-)

Comment: @Sonny You can compile your own version if you think it's infected (I'd say it's not), using the source code at a bitbucket repo linked in the same blog post: https://bitbucket.org/3mpty/atkmediainterceptor

Comment: Guys I am the blog owner, please fill in a false positive report to your antivirus vendor if you have any problem. I really don't know why it gets detected as a trojan horse T.T

Answer (score 2):

I found this gem over at autohotkey
http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=302923
it helped me map net, mail, P1 and P2 buttons on my notebook which would otherwise require some bloatware media center software to remap them. it isn't C++ but it could help you get in the right direction by looking up scan codes!

Answer (score 1):

Some laptops (like my Asus M51Sn) don't generate key presses for special (multimedia) keys. I believe those keys generate ACPI events instead. I have no idea about how to catch those. :-\

If you want to see what I've already tested, take a look at [my question at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/170238/how-to-remap-special-keys-on-asus-laptop).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I gave up on this long ago, but maybe it'll help someone else ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a project in Google Code that *disables* (intercepts) keystrokes of certain keys specified.

It's written in C but you may learn a way to do it if you go through the code.

[KillKeys](http://code.google.com/p/killkeys/)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll take a look.